# Python Voting Calculator

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to make a calculator that determines whether the user can vote after entering their date of birth. I have tried using some other posts to get where I am currently but I am now stuck.

**I have this error:**

```
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.timedelta() >= int()
```

**And my code is:**

```
from datetime import date

print("Please enter your birthday")
bd_y = input("Year: ")
bd_m = input("Month (1-12): ")
bd_d = input("Date: ")

now = date.today()

birthdate = date(int(bd_y), int(bd_m), int(bd_d))


age =  now-birthdate

print("Your age is", age)

if age >= 6570:
    print("You can vote!")
else:
    print("Your not old enough! Sorry!")
```

Any help you can give would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`age` is a Python [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) and cannot be compared with an int directly.

[`age.days`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.resolution) is the integer representation of the number of days. This can be compared to another integer.

It's worth noting that this does not include nor account for leap years, nor does it actually determine whether you can vote, as it takes the current time, rather than your age at a certain cutoff date. Additional avenues for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    from datetime import date

```
print("Please enter your birthday")
bd_y = input("Year: ")
bd_m = input("Month (1-12): ")
bd_d = input("Date: ")

now = date.today()

birthdate = date(int(bd_y), int(bd_m), int(bd_d))


age = now-birthdate

print("Your age is", age)

if age.days >= 6570:
    print("You can vote!")
else:
    print("Your not old enough! Sorry!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`age` is an object:

```
In [256]: age
Out[256]: datetime.timedelta(10188)
```

To get the total seconds, for example:

```
In [264]: age.total_seconds()
Out[264]: 880243200.0
```

To get the days:

```
In [269]: age.days
Out[269]: 10188
```

To see the attributes and methods of an object like `age` just do `dir(age)`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make things simple and just subtract the age(year only) from the current year? See below how to get current year only:

```
import datetime

print("Please enter your birthday")
bd_y = input("Year: ")
bd_m = input("Month (1-12): ")
bd_d = input("Date: ")

currentyear = datetime.date.today().year

birthdate = bd_y


age =  currentyear - int(bd_y)

print("Your age is", age)

if age >= 6570:
    print("You can vote!")
else:
    print("Your not old enough! Sorry!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your variable `age` is not simply the integer number of days. Please refer to [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) to learn more about the datatype.

The solution to your problem is choosing the correct attribute. Long story short:

`if age.days >= 6570:`

should resolve your immediate issue. Also it would be good practice to use variables to represent 6570 or at least make it clear what that number is (18 years * 365 days) in some way.

Comment: `type(age.days) = <class 'int'>`, so typecasting is not necessary.